Get text from entry with x:name
I'm working on a personal project that is working with the exception of a few minor bugs.
I have a variable called "CurrentMember" that gets the selected record from a collection view that's bonded to a database using MVVM binding context.
The CurrentMember has entries that are bound to a few entries:
mainpage.xml
<Label Text="First Name" />
<Entry x:Name="EntFName" Placeholder="First Name"
Text="{Binding CurrentMember.first_name, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<Label Text="Last Name"/>
<Entry x:Name="EntLName" Placeholder="Last Name" 
Text="{Binding CurrentMember.last_name, Mode=TwoWay}" />

<Label Text="Phone Number" x:Name="lblPhone" IsVisible="False" />
<Entry Placeholder="1234567890" x:Name="EntPhone" IsVisible="False" 
Text="{Binding CurrentMember.phone_num, Mode=TwoWay}" MaxLength="10"  ReturnCommand="{Binding SignInCommand}"/>` 

So every time I click on a record in the collection view, it changes.
I'm implementing a "search" feature to be able to search for the record without having to scroll down the collectionview.  When the fields are filled in, I'm able to get whatever the text is with the view model:
 SearchCommand = new Command(async async =>
 {

     CurrentMember = App.MemberRepo.SearchMember(CurrentMember.card_num, CurrentMember.first_name, CurrentMember.last_name, CurrentMember.phone_num);
 });


The problem is if the entries are blank, it gets what ever was selected last before emptying the field.  So the "card_num" will be 100123 when I really want it to be blank, it'll search for the card_num instead of going to the next field or saying "no user found"
I understand that it's because I'm using field that's bonded to "CurrentMember" so I'm trying to think of a way to either use the x:name or clear the "currentMember" and use what's in the field.
I know the simplest way to do this is to just use a new Entry or Searchbar but I'm trying to avoid that since the intended users are older and not tech savvy.
Any input would be awesome
I've tried to implement multi binding without success <- that's probably a me being new problem
and tried to use a normal click binding to get the x:name entries and then calling the MVVM object in multiple ways which gives me errors :

Non-invocable member 'name' cannot be used like a method.

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'member'

A method that returns a value must have a return statement in all code paths



You can use the x:name to get the item from the code behind. If you want to get it in the ViewModel, you cannot use this way.

You can check this answer about how to access the values of an entry field.

I've been playing around with this a little more..
Made a new project and a new Entry
binded it to a new string called "EntryInput"
xaml
<Entry x:Name="EntCardNum" Placeholder="Card #" Text="{Binding "EntryInput", Mode=TwoWay}"  />
cs.
public string EntryInput {  get; set; }
Even with this, I put in some text, it does it get.  Once I clear the text, the text it got before remains.  Perhaps this is just a bug or how it works with MVVM.

I ended up creating a regular click event that collects the text fields from the Entry.text and then calling the repository like a method to return the member.  It's not the way I would like to do it but seems to work.  I guess in the end, the user won't no the difference.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
